# Why is Fluent NHibernate ignoring my unique constraint on a component?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, components, unique-constraint

In my map I have:

```
Component(
    x => x.ExposureKey,
    m => {
        m.Map(x => x.AsOfDate).Not.Nullable();
        m.Map(x => x.ExposureId).Length(30).Not.Nullable();
    }
).Unique();
```

The relevant output from the HBM is

```
<component name="ExposureKey" insert="true" update="true" optimistic-lock="true" class="Some.Namespace.CreditExposureKey, Some.Namespace, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa">
    <property name="AsOfDate" type="System.DateTime, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <column name="AsOfDate" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="ExposureId" type="System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <column name="ExposureId" length="30" not-null="true"/>
    </property>
</component>
```

which is clearly missing `unique="true"` from the `component` definition.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of Fluent NHibernate? According to [**James Gregory**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/478953/how-do-i-create-a-nhibernate-mapping-file-for-a-multi-value-component-that-is-a-u/480334#480334) (Fluent NHibernate contributor), it should work.

```
// Else, try this hack:
Component(x => x.ExposureKey, m => 
{
    m.Map(x => x.AsOfDate).Not.Nullable();
    m.Map(x => x.ExposureId).Length(30).Not.Nullable();
}).SetAttribute("unique", "true");
```

It would also be good to check if the generated SQL actually has the `Unique` property set even if the hbm mapping files do not (could be a small bug).

Comment: I'll try a newer version (I'm using build 685 while current is 694). i think that `SetAttribute` has been removed. The generated SQL does not have the `unique` property set (and it shouldn't since it's not in the mapping!).

Comment: Updated to latest build (694). Still no go.

Comment: @Jason: This is odd++ and my VS at home is acting nuts. Hopefully you'll get an answer before I try replicating this at work (in about 12 hours). What is this, MSSQL/MySQL?

Comment: Both MS SQL and SQLite. I don't think that matters though as this is a problem from Fluent NHibernate to the NHibernate mapping, not from NHibernate mapping to the database commands via SchemaExport.

Comment: @Jason: just wanted to know so I could test tomorrow on the nearest environment possible. :P

Comment: @Rafael Belliard: Makes sense. Thanks for any help you can provide.